# Cant find Cordova.plist in my XCode Project

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to add a domain url to my Whitelist. The [instructions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_whitelist_index.md.html) say I must find the `Cordova.plist` file in `AppName/Supporting Files/Cordova.plist` but I dont have a directory called Supporting Files either.

I only have a `myapp-Info.plist` file and I cannot see where to add items to the whitelist on it.

I am using Cordova 2.7.0. Does anyone know what I should be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cordova 2.7.0 you wont be able to find `Cordova.plist`, it has been removed from some previous version onwards, **instead you can see a `config.xml`**, you  can set domain url to whitelist in config.xml as shown:

```
<access origin="*" />   // for all url
```

or

```
<access origin="your url" />
```